# Drude model for electron-hole gas

Tags: transport-phenomena, quantum-transport

The Drude formula for the conductivity of the electron gas reads:

$$\sigma=\frac{\sigma_0}{1-i\omega \tau}.$$

How should it be modified when the hole or electron-hole gas is under the consideration? Should it be for the holes something like

$$\sigma=\frac{\sigma_0}{1+i\omega \tau},$$

given that holes propagate backwards in time?

Comment: Why do you write $\sigma$ for holes in this particular form? Following the standard derivation of ac Drude conductivity, the conductivity for holes should be the same form as for electrons.

Comment: what does the imaginary part of conductivity mean?

Comment: It is a convention. Usually, you take the real part.